# iPad application with remote database

Tags: objective-c, ios, database

How can we implement iPad application that retrieve or store data from remote data source(Mysql). Are there any classes associate to achieve our requirement

Comment: You would need to use the MySQL C APIs. - You should try searching for information before you post here, and also ask specific questions. Take a look at - http://blog.iosplace.com/?p=20 and http://blog.iosplace.com/?p=30

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are retrieving a remote database, then I would recommend creating a wrapper for your DB using a server-side language like PHP to serve the request from your application, just like it serves an AJAX client request.

In your iOS, you have to create a NSURL instance and request your PHP application for data. Now, for returning the data you can use your own format or standards like JSON or XML. There are numerous public JSON/XML parsers available for iOS!

Comment: Further, you could watch the WWDC 2010 Session 117 video on "Building a server-driven user experience". WWDC 2010 videos are available at developer.apple.com

Answer (score 0):

How do you want to handle the delay of using a radio connection? You might want to consider using a json connection and a server application instead